# unity app crashes when admob banner ad is requested but works fine for interstitial and video ad

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, interstitial, banner-ads

I'm setting up a unity app in which i have integrated AdMob plugin. everything is working fine but when i request banner ads then app just crashes but it works fine when interstitial or video ad is requested

```
void Start()
{
 RequestBanner();
}
void RequestBanner()
{
     string banner_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
 bannerAD = new BannerView(banner_ID,AdSize.SmartBanner, AdPosition.Top);
 AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().AddTestDevice("2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b").Build();
 bannerAD.LoadAd(adRequest);
}
public void Display_Banner()
{
 bannerAD.Show();
}
void RequestInterstitial()
{
if(interstitialAd !=null)
    {
        interstitialAd.Destroy();
    }
 string interstitial_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
 interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(interstitial_ID);
 AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().AddTestDevice("2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b").Build();
 interstitialAd.LoadAd(adRequest);
}
public void Display_InterstitalAD()
{
 if(interstitialAd.IsLoaded())
 {
     interstitialAd.Show();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check is the ad loaded before showing the banner:

```
void RequestBanner()
{
    string banner_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
    bannerAD = new BannerView(banner_ID,AdSize.SmartBanner, AdPosition.Top);
    bannerAD.OnAdLoaded += HandleOnAdLoaded;
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().AddTestDevice("2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b").Build();
    bannerAD.LoadAd(adRequest);
}

public void HandleOnAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    bannerAD.Show();
}
```

Comment: how to check if the ad is loaded...
when RequestBanner() function is called unity app instantly crashes...

Comment: Have you followed the "Set your AdMob app ID" step of [Admob Guide](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/start)?

Comment: yes i have completely followed it, first time everything worked great but later on don't know what happened but everything still worked fine except banner ads...

Comment: Hard to say, do you get any errors in the adb console? I would try updating the android sdk and jdk, make sure your api level is right and reinstall the admob sdk. Also try the android resolver.